# Fluent NHibernate Many-to-Many with Conventions

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I have a many to many between two classes:

- User
- RetailOutlet

It seems that the conventions have specified the RetailOutlet as the owner for the relationship. So when I add a RetailOutlet to the collection on the User - nothing happens. I have to set both ends of the relationship.

So I try and override the mappings and:

- if I specify the ManyToMany from both sides it tells me I've duplicated mappings
- if I only specify it on one side it say something similar

I think I need to override the conventions and just tell Fluent to forget any conventions for both these classes.

I could be wrong, setting the ManyToMany in both mapping files is exactly what all the examples on the net do.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. IAutoMappingOverride.